# Array de php a variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo una consulta a la base de datos que luego traigo como array en un while

```
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $mes = $row['Mes'];
```

La salida en php es "121110987";

Luego cuando intento utilizarla mas adelante en javascript trato de utilizarla asi

```
var meses = '<?php echo $mes ?>';
```

Lo que me arroja un "7". Aqui el problema, he intentado varias maneras y aun no consigo resolverlo. Agradezco cualquier aporte!

Lo que espero que me arroje seria algo como "12,11,10,9,8,7".

Comment: $mes[] = $row['Mes'], luego var meses = '<?php echo json_encode($mes) ?>'; ... algo asi?

Comment: prueba asi: var meses ='<?=$mes?>';

Comment: Si, justo asi @Yussef. Lo habia intentado antes pero sin el [ ]. $mes = $row... Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El valor que tengas en tu variable `$mes`, puedes ponerlo en tu html de la siguiente forma:

```
<div id="var"> <?php echo $mes ?> </div>
```

Y en tu javascript obtendrías lo que contiene dicho `id` y almacenarlo en una variable:

```
let text = document.getElementById("var").textContent;
console.log(text); //121110987
```